# Using CountA on one row ONLY and also using the cells found and putting them somewhere else

Tags: excel, vba

So I am learning VBA, I know how to program on Matlab and some C++. I am wondering how I can use the CountA to count all of the cells used on a specific row and only that row. ( I have multiple examples on ranges and columns but none on a Row only).I cannot use a range because I want to use this VBA in the future and this row will have a number of variables changing. I would also like to have the content(text) of those cells moved to another location with no spaces between them because right now they have three spaces between each used cell.

So far I have this code which isn't very much for the countA of the first row

```
Sub CountNonBlankCells()
    Dim numcompanies As Integer
    n = Sheet1.CountA(Rows(1))
    Worksheets("start on this page").Range("B2") = n
End Sub
```

I have nothing for the part where I take that data from each cell to another location.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use a Range. Your question is pretty broad, but for tutorial purpose ... here's a piece of code that counts the number of nonblank cells in a number of rows and shows you what's in each of them ...

```
Sub TestCount()
Dim mySht As Worksheet
Dim myRng As Range, oRow As Range
Dim lstRow As Long, lstCol As Long
Dim nUsed As Long
Dim iLoop As Long

Set mySht = Worksheets("Sheet13")
lstRow = mySht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lstCol = mySht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
Set myRng = mySht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lstRow, lstCol))

Debug.Print "Number of Rows is " & myRng.Rows.Count
For Each oRow In myRng.Rows
    nUsed = Application.CountA(oRow)
    For iLoop = 1 To nUsed
        Debug.Print oRow.Cells(1, iLoop)
    ' assign oRow.Cells(1,iLoop) to something else here
    Next iLoop
Next oRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I am assuming that you want to copy a complete row having blank cells to another location(row) but without blank cells.

I guess this is what you want.

```
Sub CountNonBlankCells()

    Dim CurrentSh As Worksheet, TargetSh As Worksheet
    Dim LastColumn As Long, count As Long
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim i As Long, temp As Long
    Dim RowNum As Long

    Set CurrentSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set TargetSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    RowNum = ActiveCell.Row
    LastColumn = CurrentSh.Cells(RowNum, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set MyRange = CurrentSh.Rows(RowNum)
    count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyRange)

    temp = 1
    For i = 1 To LastColumn
        If Not IsEmpty(CurrentSh.Cells(RowNum, i)) Then
            TargetSh.Cells(RowNum, temp).Value = CurrentSh.Cells(RowNum, i).Value
            temp = temp + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Above code will copy active row in `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` at same row number without blank cells.